# A $\pm$ in a Vector Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I am following a derivation in a [book](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=P4TKxn7qW5kC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Bryson and Ho. The problem is for path calculation in a velocity field (wind). Wind is $w = \vec{w}$ position $r = \vec{r}$ and control heading $\hat{u} = \vec{\hat{u}}$ where $\hat{u} \cdot \hat{u} = 1$.

Aircraft velocity equation:

$$
\dot{r} = V \hat{u} + w
$$

Hamiltonian

$$
\mathcal{H} = \lambda \cdot (V \hat{u}  + w) + 
\mu (1 - \hat{u}\cdot\hat{u}) + 1
$$

Euler-Lagrange

$$
\dot{\lambda} = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial r} = - \nabla (\lambda \cdot w)
$$

$$
0 = \frac{\partial H}{\partial \hat{u}} = V \lambda - 2\mu\hat{u}
$$

Then, using the last equation above, the author says

$$
2\mu = \pm V |\lambda| \to \hat{u} = \pm \frac{\lambda}{|\lambda|}
$$

I understand the algebra except the $\pm$ part.. Why was that necessary?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$V\lambda = 2 \mu \hat{u}$$
Which means that their direction is the same, so we can write that
$$\hat{u}=C \lambda$$
for some $C$. But because $\hat{u}$ is an unit vector, we must have that
$$|C|\, ||\lambda|| = 1$$
Which means that
$$|C| = \frac{1}{||\lambda||}$$
But $C$ can be positive and negative as well, that's why we write
$$\hat{u}=\pm |C| \lambda = \pm \frac{\lambda}{||\lambda||}$$
And we will pick the appropriate sign later (which will make the Hamiltonian zero, as I can see).

Comment: Hi. So after the $\hat{u} = C \lambda$ couldn't you already say $C = 1/|\lambda|$ which would satisfy the equation?

Comment: @BBDynSys No. What if $\frac{V}{2 \mu}$ is negative?

Comment: @BBDynSys A simple example: If $\lambda = -2 \hat{u}$, then $|\lambda|=2$, but $\lambda \neq 2 \hat{u}$.

Comment: From the description of the problem, it appears $V$ is given, a constant velocity so it can be assumed positive? $\mu$ is a multiplier, time dependent $\mu(t)$.. that could become negative.. yes. So by using $|C| ||\lambda|| = 1$ you are protected from the side effects..

Comment: @BBDynSys I'm not familiar with the problem, but if $V$ is the speed of the wind, then (based on my real-life experiences) it can be negative as well. But of course, if the exercise says so we can have positive $V$ only. But if it is not stated, it's better to not assume it.

Comment: OK. One more dumb question. Now that we know $\hat{u} = \pm \lambda / |\lambda|$, then the author says "since we know $\mathcal{H}=0$, we must have $\hat{u} = -\lambda / |\lambda|$ or $\hat{u} = -\hat{\lambda}$". How does he get that? I put the $\hat{u} = -\hat{\lambda}$ back in the Hamiltonian, canceling the term with $\hat{u}'s$ at the end (they are zero), but the rest didn't seem to suggest anything. I am not sure what to do with $w$.

Comment: @BBDynSys Honestly, I can't see it in the equations. But looking at the picture, we see that $\dot{r} \cdot \hat{u}>0$, the second term in the hamiltonian is zero, and the third one is positive. So the only possible way for it to be zero if the first term is negative, which means that $\hat{\lambda}=-\hat{u}$.